# how can i quickly optimize this mesh out from a curve?

Tags: modeling, topology, bmesh, optimization

this is a hair that i have done for my character there, so its made out from a curve, after convert it to mesh, it gave me too much verts or poly count, i need to optimize it, i tried the unsubdivide option but it gaves me a weird result because of the triangules topology, and decimate modifier but its ugly as fuck the shape and topology, the the result that i want its the first that i tried but unfortunately that issue happened.. its there a better way to optimize this kind of meshes?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried a ctrl E > Un-subdivide? Play a bit with the iteration value on the bottom of the Tools panel, then again try to re-Un-subdivide... it might work... at the end I guess you'll need to make so manual corrections... Also, select ring, then checker deselect, then select loops, then dissolve... but maybe share this part of your file so that we can try?

Comment: ok wait a moment...yes i tried ctrl+e unsubdivide...uploading blend file

Comment: never mind i already fixed it

Comment: so what method did you use?

Comment: the one from the below answer

Comment: oh ok I thought you had found a solution for the mesh

Comment: actually you told me wrong, i had to select the rings with ctrl+alt+right click, then checker deselect, edge loops select, and delete edge loops, like in this video that i found today https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttU6Gz1W0Xw

Comment: so what did I tell wrong?

Comment: ctrl+alt+right click, you missed that part...

Comment: ctrl+alt+right click is select ring, exactly what I explained on my first post, I just needed your file to give it a test and make some screenshots... anyway you've found your solution and that's what matters   ;)

Comment: anyways i used your metod here xD https://www.artstation.com/artwork/8l5QX6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to tweak the curve properties before converting it to a mesh. The *Resolution* values get you control over the density of your model, so you can increase or decrease the number of polygons.

[image]

And my suggestion is to active the wire/draw all edges options in the *Object>Display* properties so you can have a nice preview of how many polygons you will have your object after the conversion.

[image]